# symfony2 : Sql Syntax Error

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I want to display the list of papers with more That a reporter , but I think I have a problem in my sql query syntax .. here is the whole function in my controller :

```
`public function nonattribuéAction()
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('administrationadministrationBundle:Papier');
    $repository = $em->getRepository('administrationadministrationBundle:CorrectionPap');
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT * FROM administaration\administrationBundle\Entity\Papier WHERE pNum IN (SELECT DISTINCT pNum FROM administaration\administrationBundle\Entity\CorrectionPapier GROUP BY pNum HAVING COUNT(rNum)=>0)');
    $papier = $query->getResult();
    return $this->render('administrationadministrationBundle:Default:papier.html.twig', array('papier' => $papier, 'name' => 'Papiers Non Attribués'));
}`
```

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be in English.

Comment: Google translate helped me ;p [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.in/#auto/en/Salut%2C%20Je%20veux%20afficher%20la%20liste%20des%20papiers%20ayant%20plus%20q'un%20rapporteur%2C%20mais%20je%20crois%20que%20j'ai%20un%20probl%C3%A8me%20dans%20le%20Syntaxe%20de%20ma%20requ%C3%AAte%20sql%20..%20voila%20toute%20la%20fonction%20dans%20mon%20contr%C3%B4leur%20%3A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer :D

```
 public function nonattribuéAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM administrationadministrationBundle:Papier u WHERE u.pNum IN (SELECT DISTINCT v.pNum FROM administrationadministrationBundle:CorrectionPap v GROUP BY v.pNum HAVING COUNT(v.rNum)= 2)');
    $results = $query->getResult();
    return $this->render('administrationadministrationBundle:Default:papier.html.twig', array('papier' => $results, 'name' => 'Papiers Non Attribués'));
}
```